# Horizontally center wide images in container, crop left/right if necessary

Tags: html, css, jquery-cycle2

I have several images inside a container and I would like the images to be centered horizontally when the browser is resized. Currently, images align with the left edge like `left: 0`, I want them to overflow outside the left and right edge if container is narrower than the image. I thought `margin: 0 auto` would work. But it seems it doesn't. Basically this is what I want:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid main-slide">
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <div class="cycle-slideshow" style="position: relative;">
      <img src="/img/1.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; min-width:100%; position: absolute; top:50%; transform: translateY(-30%);display:block;">
      <img src="/img/2.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; min-width:100%; position: absolute; top:50%; transform: translateY(-30%);display:block;">
      <img src="/img/3.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; min-width:100%; position: absolute; top:50%; transform: translateY(-30%);display:block;">
      <img src="/img/4.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; min-width:100%; position: absolute; top:50%; transform: translateY(-30%);display:block;">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-slide{
    height:520px; 
    width:100%; 
    max-width:1920px;
    padding:0; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljnzr2uu/)

Comment: can you put this in a pen or fiddle?\

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fs52sp8j/

Comment: margin 0 will not place image at left:0 . Do you want images to take entire view port width and position them from left top of view port ?

Comment: I didn't say `margin 0 auto` would place image at left. I said they are like `left:0` when I resize the browser. And I want them to center like the image I posted.

Comment: Fiddle added. When you resize down the browser image will stay left:0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following trick will center an image horizontally even if that requires pushing the left side outside the container.

```css
.cycle-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  /* for testing */
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 10px solid #FC0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.cycle-slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* fill vertically */
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  /* center horizontally */
  left: -1000px;
  right: -1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* for testing */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main-slide">
  <div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/800x200/000/fff">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x200/000/fff" style="display: none;">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" style="display: none;">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" style="display: none;">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- cycle plugin will cycle the images one by one -->
```

[**Updated Fiddle that uses cycle plugin**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Ljnzr2uu/3/)

Comment: See **http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Ljnzr2uu/3/** (i) cycle plugin adds `left:` on the image tag so added `!important` in CSS (ii) I have removed stretch to fit rules since cycle plugin automatically grows the container to fit tallest image (iii) I have used wider images as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

#### here's a fiddle for you; I think this is what you're looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/qo625xkb/

just added a slide class to your imgs. and...

```
<div class="container-fluid main-slide">
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <div class="cycle-slideshow" style="position: relative;">
  <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />      
  <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"  />      
  <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />      
  <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
</div>
```

took a different approach with the full container, center fill.

```
.main-slide{
    height:520px; 
    max-width:1920px;
    padding:0;  
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 50%;
}
```